# Unable To Close A Form Embedded In A Panel

Tags: vb.net, forms, panel

I have an issue that is really starting to do my head in...
My application has a ListView control that is populated with items.  When you double click on an item it creates a new instance of a form.  It then creates a new panel and adds the form to the panel.  However, for the life of me I cannot work out how to close the form inside the panel.

Inside my DoubleClick event:

```
Dim frm As New frmStorePage(_store.Code, _store.Name)

'Create a new panel with the store page
Dim pnl As New Panel
pnl.Name = _store.Code
pnl.BackColor = SystemColors.Control
pnl.Size = New Size(1522, 892)
pnl.Location = New Point(3, 3)
frm.TopLevel = False
frm.Name = _store.Code
pnl.Controls.Add(frm)
frm.Show()
pnlStores.Controls.Add(pnl)
pnl.BringToFront()
...
```

Inside my Close event:

```
Dim panel As Panel = CType(pnlStores.Controls.Find(lsvOpenStoreList.SelectedItems(0).Name, False)(0), Windows.Forms.Panel)

For Each control As Control In panel.Controls
   If TypeOf control Is Windows.Forms.Form And control.Name = panel.Name Then
        control.Dispose()
   End If
Next

pnlStores.Controls.Remove(panel)
panel.Dispose()
pnlStoreList.BringToFront()
...
```

I have also tried declaring my form as a global variable but still cannot seem to close it.
The form has a number of timer events that get stopped when the form closes, however, even though the panel gets closed, the timer events are still running.  It seems that the form is still active in the background.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In 16 years of programming with VB, I had no idea you could add a form to a panel! But, have you tried calling 'ctype(control,form).close' method before the dispose? I would think dispose would do it but it obviously does not in this case.

Comment: Thanks Steve, but nope - didn't sort it unfortunately. I can tell this form is still running because I have Timer.Stop events attached to the form close method.  One of these timers is giving me an error everytime it executes and when I close the panel/form, I am still getting this error popup from the timer.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I did some code to put a form (with timer that starts on load and stops when closed) in a panel and as long as the form is shown, it runs my timer and when I tell the form to close, it stops running it.  I used most of your code you supplied so it must be something else that isn't here.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? <br/>
I'd put a breakpoint at the For Each statement, see what each Control type and name is, and then compare this to your If statement to see if it is a match. I imagine the fault lies somewhere in this logic. If you want to send me your source, i'd be more than happy to review it.

    For Each control As Control In panel.Controls
       If TypeOf control Is Windows.Forms.Form And control.Name = panel.Name Then
            control.Dispose()
       End If
    Next

Comment: Oh whoops, I thought I had closed this issue.  I posted the comment but must not have saved it.  Anyway, due to a lack of thoroughness I failed to see that the code I was using to dispose of all the controls and close the form was not in the FormClosing event, but under a Command Button called Close.  Therefore, my closing procedures were never getting called and thus the timers remained active.  All good now and working great.  I just don't know how to close this issue without an answer being added.

Comment: @Riples Make this the answer and mark it answered so it can be closed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to a silly oversight, I failed to see that the code I was using to dispose of all the controls and close the form was not in the FormClosing event, but actually under a Command Button called Close. Therefore, my closing procedures were never getting called and thus the timers remained active.

Thanks